# Reusing a UITableView footer view in multiple views

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have a footer for a `UITableView` which is a "complex" view (textView and a button).
I made a xib and added it to the footer of the `UITableView`.
The next stage is having referencing outlets in the ViewController of the `UITableView`
The thing is that I want to use this footer view in several `ViewControllers` (and not DRYing)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a xib/.h/.m separate from the .xib used by your `UIViewController`. This is for your View that will be used as the footer of the `UITableView`. You can `[[MyFooterView alloc] init]` in the `viewDidLoad` of any controllers that are using a `UITableView` and assign the footer to that instance of `MyFooterView`.  Is this what you're after? You can still have referencing outlets to the `UITableView` in any `UIViewController`, and keep a reference to `MyFooterView` that you instantiated in `viewDidLoad`

addTarget example:

```
myFooterView.button addTarget:self action:myCustomHandlerFunction forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

Comment: that's what I'm after, but how do I reference it's objects without an h/m file? (assign event to the button etc.)

Comment: Use addTarget from UIControl, updated in original answer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: Got it - and what class should this object inherit from? UIView?

Comment: got it. Ended up using tags and avoiding h/m file - but your solution is a valid one. 10X!